# How to remove prefilled value "false" from android EditText field?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/lad_label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/lad_label" />
<EditText
android:text="@+id/lade_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
android:text="@+id/lami_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Here's what I've tried to do (in main.xml) but whenever I run the program a prefilled value of "false" appears in all the edittext fields. And I want to remove them. Any help will really be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to the EditText documentation instead of just assuming there is somethign wrong with the code. if you're going to use something at the very least understand what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Give the edit text some default value. Or may be give the value as a blank string.

```
android:text=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are passing the values to wrong place,

```
    <EditText
android:text="@+id/lade_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
android:text="@+id/lami_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

i guess you were trying to set **android:id="@+id/lami_name**

Then add your text to the two editboxes below as you did for the first one:  `android:text="@string/lad_label"`